# MVC3 routes - how to separate after the last dash in url?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, routes

Given the following routes:

```
        routes.MapRoute(name: "CityHomePage1", url: "{city}-{state}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "GeoHomePage" });
        routes.MapRoute(name: "CityHomePage2", url: "{city}-{state}/", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "GeoHomePage" });
        routes.MapRoute(name: "CityStateResults", url: "{city}-{state}/{searchTerm}", defaults: new { controller = "Results", action = "SearchCityState" });
        routes.MapRoute(name: "CityStateCategoryResults", url: "{city}-{state}/{category}/{searchTerm}", defaults: new { controller = "Results", action = "SearchCityStateCategory" });
```

This works well when the cities do not have dashes ("-") in them, however I am now changing the way multiple cities are displayed in the URL from having an underscore between them, to now having dashes.

So, if the URL reads http://www.site.com/Gardena-Ceretos-Santa_Monica-California/someterm it the routes will no longer work.

How would I grab the state as everything after the last "-" and before the "/" in my routes to extract the state?

Looking at this now, I should have structured the URLS as /city-city-city/state/searchtearm, but for now, I have to stick with the current structure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a situation where routing does not have any tools to assist you.  There are two options.

First, change your token to `{cityState}`, make that the parameter in your action methods, and parse the cityState string in your controller actions.

Second, change your token to `{cityState}` (I promise, this is a different option), and then use a custom RouteHandler to parse the cityState string, and add city and state route tokens to pass to your existing actions.  The RouteHandler would look like so:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;   
using System.Web.Routing;   

public class MyRouteHandler : IRouteHandler   
{   
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)   
    {   
        var routeData = requestContext.RouteData;   
        var cityState = routeData.Values["cityState"].ToString();
        var parts = cityState.Split(new string[] { "-" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var state = parts.Last();
        var citySb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var part in parts)
        {
            if (part != state)
            {
                if (citySb.Length > 0)
                    citySb.Append("-");
                citySb.Append(part);
            }
        }
        routeData.Values.Add("city", citySb.ToString());
        routeData.Values.Add("state", state);
        var handler = new MvcHandler(requestContext);   
        return handler;   
    }   
}
```

Then, change each of your routes to be similar to this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "CityHomePage1", 
    new Route(
        "{cityState}",   
        new RouteValueDictionary(   
            new { controller = "Home", action = "GeoHomePage" }),   
            new MyRouteHandler()  
        )
    )  
);
```

Comment: Where you would have a two part city, ie "Santa_Monica", that would be retained with the "_", as "Santa" and "Monica" alone are not a match, then get the state from the Last() part of the array.  I see how that works, however, in terms of SEO, there needs to be separation between all cities/states, so that's why I needed it structured separately.  I was thinking of a regex solution, maybe?

Comment: In your question, you said you have to stick with the original structure.  Have you changed your mind?  If you have not changed your mind, what do you mean that you need it structured separately?